# Applescript Purge Email Older than 2 Days

Tags: macos, email, applescript, purge, recycle-bin

I am new to Applescript. I have one specific email account that exists solely for the purpose receiving error reports with an attached image. The mailbox can fill up quickly.

I'd like to be able to run a script that will delete mail older than two days, so I tried my hand at the following script.

I'd like to correct what I have written so I can learn from my mistakes rather that use a different method. Looking for some constructive criticism:

```
set daysToPreserve to 2

tell application "Mail"
activate
set mailboxList to mailbox "INBOX" of account “MyAccount"
repeat with theCurrentMailbox in mailboxList
    set emailList to (every message of (mailbox theCurrentMailbox of account “MyAccount") whose date received is less than or equal to ((current date) - daysToPreserve * days))
    if (count mailboxList) is greater than 0 then
        move mailboxList to mailbox "Trash" of account “MyAccount"
    end if
end repeat
end tell

display dialog "Old Mail Messages Have Been Purged" buttons ["OK"]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You put 1 item into a repeat block with this:

```
set mailboxList to mailbox "INBOX" of account “MyAccount"
repeat with theCurrentMailbox in mailboxList
```

You can try something like this:

```
set daysToPreserve to 2
set myAcount to "MyAccount"
set dateReference to (current date) - (daysToPreserve * days)

tell application "Mail"
    activate
    set myMailbox to mailbox "INBOX" of account myAcount
    set accountTrash to mailbox "Trash" of account myAcount
    set messagesToDelete to messages of myMailbox whose date received ≤ dateReference
    repeat with aMessage in messagesToDelete
        move aMessage to accountTrash
    end repeat
end tell

display dialog (count messagesToDelete) & " old Mail Messages Have Been Purged" as text buttons ["OK"]
```

Comment: This works correctly only if I remove:

    display dialog (count messagesToDelete) & " old Mail Messages Have Been Purged"

Otherwise I see error:

error "Can’t make {1, \" old Mail Messages Have Been Purged \"} into type string." number -1700 from {1, " old Mail Messages Have Been Purged"} to string

Answer (score 2):

Your edit worked great. I edited your script to bring the dialog to the front.

```
set daysToPreserve to 2
set myAcount to "MyAccount"
set dateReference to (current date) - (daysToPreserve * days)

tell application "Mail"
  activate
  set myMailbox to mailbox "INBOX" of account myAcount
  set accountTrash to mailbox "Trash" of account myAcount
  set messagesToDelete to messages of myMailbox whose date received ≤ dateReference
  repeat with aMessage in messagesToDelete
  move aMessage to accountTrash
end repeat
end tell

tell current application
  activate
  display dialog (count messagesToDelete) & " old Mail Messages Have Been Purged" as    text buttons ["OK"]
end tell
```

Answer (score 0):

this version tests number of versions to move before continuing

#[Applescript Purge Email Older than 2 Days](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22424448/applescript-purge-email-older-than-2-days)

```
set daysToPreserve to 7
set myAccount to "MyEmail Account"
set dateReference to (current date) - (daysToPreserve * days)

tell application "Mail"
    activate
    set myMailbox to mailbox "INBOX/7 days" of account myAccount
    set accountTrash to mailbox "Trash" of account myAccount
    set messagesToDelete to messages of myMailbox whose date received ≤ dateReference
    
    if (count messagesToDelete) as number = 0 then
        return
    end if

    repeat with aMessage in messagesToDelete
        move aMessage to accountTrash
    end repeat
end tell

tell current application
    activate
    display notification (count messagesToDelete) & " old messages have been purged from folder 7 days" as text
    delay 1
end tell
```